# I have a button and a gesture recognition and when the button is pressed only one method should be called

Tags: iphone, ios6, uibutton, xcode4.5, uigesturerecognizer

I have a button and a gesture recognition and when the button is pressed only one method should be called.

Most cases only the gesture recognition is being called which is fine but every no and then the button gets called to which causes problems.

I have a view and then a scroll view. All my buttons are on the scroll view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can implement this in your view controller and assign it to the delegate of the gesture recognizer.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.view];
    UIView *view = [sefl.view hitTest:p withEvent:nil];
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

or you can implement `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch` with similar logic if `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` does not suit.

Comment: Thanks a million. For beginners like myself you don't know how to assign the delegate in code: [recognizer setDelegate:self];                 I know its bad but I have always used the automatic way of assigning delegater. I wish books and tutorials would so both ways.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with `[recognizer setDelegate:self]` as long as `self` implements `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`